# Applying a Quantile Loss Function to Optimize an Exponential Smoothing Model

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I have tried posting on others places without luck so I am going to try here as well.

I am trying to build a model that generate prediction intervals from a traditional winters-holt forecast model. There is a built-in function that does it in statmodels but there are a few missing features preventing me from fully depend on it. I am looking for a critic eye and don't know anywhere else to post:

What I did is use a quantile loss pinball function to optimize the parameters (level, trend and seasonality) of the model and generate different forecast corresponding to different quantile values that I input in the quantile loss function.

first of all: is it good practice to optimize the parameters for a quantile

second, is the described process viable to get prediction intervals?

Now, in the results dataset, I observe none difference between predictions made with a quantile of 0.05 and a 0.95 or worst, there are even timeseries where the results give lower values for the 0.95 quantile value.

I am confused and wondered what could be wrong in the method knowing that the model works just fine with finding regular point series using mean square error loss function

here is my quantile loss function:

```
def quantile_loss(q,y_p, y):
    a = np.where((y > y_p), q *(y-y_p), (y_p - y)*(1-q))

    return a
```

and here is the code for the parameter optimization:

```
def HoltWinterLowHightimeseriesCVscore(params,quantile_values, data, loss_function=quantile_loss,slen=12):
    """
        Returns error on CV

        params - vector of parameters for optimization
        series - dataset with timeseries
        slen - season length for Holt-Winters model
    """
    # errors array
    errors = []

    values = data
    alpha, beta, gamma = params

    # set the number of folds for cross-validation
    tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3)

    # iterating over folds, train model on each, forecast and calculate error
    for train, test in tscv.split(values):
        model = HoltWintersLowHigh(series=values, slen=slen,
                            alpha=alpha, beta=beta, gamma=gamma, n_preds=12)
        model.triple_exponential_smoothing()
        predictions = model.result[-len(test):]
        actual = values[test]
        error = loss_function(quantile, predictions, actual)
        errors.append(error)

    return np.mean(np.array(errors))
```

and finally here is the final part where the functions are called to make the predictions:

```
forecast = {}

for i in seasonal_profile_df.index:
    quantile_values = [0.92]

    if seasonal_profile_df['trend'].loc[i] == 'trending' and seasonal_profile_df['seasonality'].loc[i] == 'seasonal' and seasonal_profile_df['demand_level'].loc[i] == 'low' or seasonal_profile_df['variability'].loc[i] == 'high':

        index = pd.DatetimeIndex(new_df.index)
        series = pd.Series(data=new_df.iloc[:, i], index=index)
        print(len(series))
        data = series[:-10]  #leave some data for testing
        x = [0, 0, 0]
        #for i in quantile:

        for j in quantile_values:
            quantile_values = j
    # Minimizing the loss function
            opt = minimize(HoltWinterLowHightimeseriesCVscore, x0=x,
                       args=( quantile_values,data, quantile_loss,),
                       method="TNC", bounds=((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
                       )
            alpha_final, beta_final, gamma_final = opt.x
            print(opt.x)

##and then predict according to the quantile specified #####
            model = HoltWintersLowHigh(series, slen=12,
                                alpha=alpha_final,
                                beta=beta_final,
                                gamma=gamma_final,
                                n_preds=12, scaling_factor=1.96)
            model.triple_exponential_smoothing()
            plotHoltWintersLowHigh(series, quantile_values)

            result= {"Id": seasonal_profile_df['Id'].loc[i]}
            result['results'] = model.result[-12:]
```

I am really hoping to get a fresh or more experienced eye on this. I feel like the process make sense but I cannot find a solid example in python, and I would like if someone could tell me whether the approach does not make sense or if there is a problematic thing with the code. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Its very interesting.  Have a look at the papers on TFT and DeepAR and others that use quantile based cost function.  Seems to be becoming standard on the Deep Learning side so might be useful references and validations there?  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.09363.pdf

Comment: thanks for the link, it kinda blew my mind!